# Start on first blank row and declaring variable for counter in For..Next Loop in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The code below is a simple formula repeater. I had one that worked fine, but I want to move away from `select` and `activate` and start declaring variables so code is easier to read.

I basically want to press my shortcut and have the code start from the first blank row in column F (starting from F4). Then I want the code to enter a formula using values in this format: Formula( ValueTwoColumnsLeft, ValueOneColumnLeft).

The thing I really need help on is understanding For..Next loops. For the part `For StartCell = 1 To 2500`, I do not understand what the `i` is supposed to be or how I should define it. I know it can't be a range, then it doesn't make sense anymore.

```
Sub FormulaRepeater()

' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Address As Range
Dim rowcount As Long
Dim Latitude As String
Dim Longitude As String
Dim result As String
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("S2")
Set Address = sht.Range("F4").End(xlDown)

rowcount = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, Address) 'start from first blank row in F
Set StartCell = sht.Cells(rowcount + 1, Address)

Latitude = Cells.Offset(0, -2).Value ' get latitude 2 cells to the left
Longitude = Cells.Offset(0, -1).Value 'get longitude 1 cell to the left
'Would using offset here be the same as select i.e. sets Application.ScreenUpdating=True

For rowcount = StartCell To 10 'from the selected cell to 2500, _
which is the daily limit for the Google API

        result = GEOAddress(Latitude, Longitude)


    Next
End Sub
```

P.S don't worry about the formula itsel, it works on it's own. Yes I can drag it down but I am trying to practice. Getting type mismatch on defining rowcount ATM.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are looking for this

```
Sub FormulaRepeater()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim rowcount As Long
    Dim Latitude As String
    Dim Longitude As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim StartCell As Long
    Set sht = Worksheets("S2")
    StartCell = sht.Range("F4").End(xlDown).Row
    rowcount = sht.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'start from first blank row in F
    For i = StartCell To rowcount
        Latitude = sht.Range("F" & i).Offset(0, -2).Value ' get latitude 2 cells to the left
        Longitude = sht.Range("F" & i).Offset(0, -1).Value 'get longitude 1 cell to the left
        result = GEOAddress(Latitude, Longitude)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, although you forgot to declare the worksheet!

Unfortunately, this gives me the same issue as the title. The counter AKA "i" is not defined. I don't know what this means...

I do really like the starting from the bottom for the row method, eliminates the need for the +1. Great tip!

Comment: @J.H, see the edited code. purpose of "i" is to get the corresponding latitute and longiture from the F column

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Next i" at the end of the loop? Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: @SunnyOnesotrue, its a single loop.. it does not require i

Comment: I think I have figured it out. What I was missing and what you are also missing was: 
'Dim i As Integer'